# BigDecimal format with exponential

Tags: java, bigdecimal, exponential, largenumber

I have a problem with formating `BigDecimal` in Java (Android Studio)!

I want to format `BigDecimal` to `String` when it is **bigger than** 16 characters, with **9 decimals plus exponential** (`0.000000000e+00`).

I used `String#format` but the result is not correct, it is `1.000000000e+32` instead of `9.99999999e+31`.

How can I get the number in the correct format? Here is the code.

```
String b = "9999999999999999";
String c = "9999999999999999";
BigDecimal resultMultyply = (new BigDecimal(b)).multiply(new BigDecimal(c));
String main_number = resultMultyply.toString();

if (main_number.length() > 16) {
    // main_number = 99999999999999980000000000000001
    main_number = String.format("%16.9e", new BigDecimal(main_number));
    // main_number = 1.000000000e+32
}
```

`main_number` is correct before formatting.

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: The code you posted is it JS?

Comment: Javascript =/= Java

Comment: use a similar library to big.js or treat the number as a string and therefore you would need to ensure that the number is not converted back to a number. the answer is for Javascript, i have realised that the code you pasted is in Java.

Comment: No. it's in Java. My mistake!!

Comment: Why is the result not correct? It is a simple rounding issue. The difference between your two numbers is very minimal.

Comment: Because I am working on a calculator and I need a precise answer.

Answer (score 2):

## Use `DecimalFormat` with rounding mode `DOWN`

Your problem is that you don't have your hands on the rounding mode when creating your output value. The default rounding mode for `BigDecimal` is `HALF_UP`, which is not what you want: you want to see the first digits as is. So that means you discard the digits after your expected precision, which translates into rounding `DOWN`. Unfortunately, `BigDecimal` doesn't offer such fine grain by default. So you have to use `DecimalFormat`.

All in all, it works like this:

```
import java.math.*;
import java.text.*;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("9999999999999999");
    BigDecimal mul = a.multiply(a);
    System.out.println(format(mul, 9));
  }

  private static String format(BigDecimal x, int scale) {
    NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.0E0");
    formatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
    formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(scale);
    return formatter.format(x);
  }

}
```

Outputs:

```
9.999999999E31
```

Comment: It works in Eclipse, but in Android Studio with same code I get 1.000000000E32.

Comment: @TonyKalo You didn't specify Android Studio at all in your question: this is Java as is, not Android-Studio-flavored Java. You should probably check if there are no other way doing so with Android Studio. However I see it's fairly similar to Java, so you should actually get the same result, unless there's a bug? I would doubt it, though.

Comment: Sorry I'm new here. Thanks!